# How to package a command line software to an Application in MacOS

Tags: macos

I have a command line executable (written in C) with some related resources, and I would like to package it as an application (inside the .app folder). I tried `appify.sh` which could package shell script, but didn't work here. For this command line executable, I would like to open termial to show the STDOUT.

I also found [this method using Automator](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99435/how-to-make-a-command-line-executable-an-application) , but didn't find how to package the executable and resources inside the folder. Should I write an Info.plist file? I tried but failed to get the Terminal opened and run the executable.

Comment: How do you expect a command-line executable to behave as an app? Does it have a GUI?

Comment: Nope, but if I double click the binary file, a terminal window will pop up and run it, same as on Windows and Linux, which is all I want. An app looks more comfortable for users than ‘unzip it and double click the file’.

Comment: If you follow @tubedogg's instructions in reply to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99435/how-to-make-a-command-line-executable-an-application) you'll have all you need. Just drag the icon to /Applications.